# Allow certain url in nginx and restrict all other requests

Tags: nginx

I want to allow certain url for public and block all request in nginx configuration. For example:

*/abc/xyz/* should be publicly accessible and all other requests should be blocked. I tried following

```
location ~^(sa|er|fgh)/abc/xyz{ ... }
```

and

```
location ~ ^/abc/xyz$ { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to allow all the urls which include /abc/xyz then use:

```
location ~*/abc/xyz* { ... }
```

All other URL's not containing /abc/xyz will return 404.

Note: run: `nginx -t` to check for errors then restart nginx service.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: This doesn't check the URI. Will check only folders and files.